# Rewriterule doesn't work if I use absolute paths

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This:

```
rewriteengine on
rewriterule test /index.php
```

.works. This:

```
rewriteengine on
rewriterule test index.php
```

.works. This:

```
rewriteengine on
rewriterule index.php index.php
```

.works.

But this:

```
rewriteengine on
rewriterule index.php /index.php
```

.gives me 500 internal server error.

How is it that `index.php index.php` works, yet `index.php /index.php` doesn't?

What's causing this error?

Comment: Check the error log. It is almost certainly an infinite rewrite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because you asked for the **WHY** I will share some insights on it.

For this `rewriterule index.php index.php` instruction Apache recognize that the origin and the destination is the same `initial URL equal rewritten URL` and therefor `[IGNORING REWRITE]`

The second one is not 100% the same so Apache try to execute it. But because the slash makes not really any differences we rewrite index.php to /index.php and after each rewrite Apache checks all rewrite instructions for the new destination again, and now we end up in an infinite rewrite loop.

Just set the log level `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` in your configuration and you can see it your self.